# SQL Merge jsons

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Template with Id , TemplateValue which is nvarchar column

```
Id  TemplateValue

1   {"WorkflowName": "Test","GlobalParams":[{"Name":"abc","Expression":"testexp"}],"Rules": []}
```

And another table Rules has RuleJson column which is also nvarchar

```
Id  RuleJson

1   {"RuleName":"a","expression":"1=1"}
2   {"RuleName":"b","expression":"1=1"}
```

I want to merge json from these tables such a way that `Rules` array node present in `Template`  table should be updated with `RuleJson` which is present in `Rules` json table in different rows.

The output should be like:

```
{
  "WorkflowName": "Test",
  "GlobalParams": [
    {
      "Name": "abc",
      "Expression": "testexp"
    }
  ],
  "Rules": [
    {
      "RuleName": "a",
      "expression": "1=1"
    },
    {
      "RuleName": "b",
      "expression": "1=1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `JSON_MODIFY`, but not able to merge the json as expected.

Comment: Is there a (good) reason why you're storing JSON in a table column instead of having a normalized table design?

Comment: _"I tried using JSON_MODIFY but not able to merge the json as expected"_ - you need to tell us what problems you had with `JSON_MODIFY`.

Comment: You know JSON columns are, like **REALLY** slow, right?

Comment: `select 
json_modify(
'{"WorkflowName": "Test","GlobalParams":[{"Name":"abc","Expression":"testexp"}],"Rules": []}',
'$.Rules', json_query(
(select '['+string_agg(RuleJson,',') within group(order by Id)+']'
from(values(1, '{"RuleName":"a","expression":"1=1"}'),(2, '{"RuleName":"b","expression":"1=1"}')
) as Rules (Id, RuleJson)
))
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `JSON_MODIFY` using something like the following:

```
SELECT  t.Id,
        t.TemplateValue,
        NewRules = JSON_QUERY(r.Rules),
        CombinedJson = JSON_MODIFY(TemplateValue, 
                                  'append $.Rules', 
                                  JSON_QUERY(r.Rules))
FROM    dbo.Template AS t
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(r.RuleJson, ','), ']') 
            FROM    dbo.Rules AS r
        ) AS r (Rules);
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ynSUZGVD)**

Unfortunately I have not found a more elegant way of creating the rule array other than using `STRING_AGG` and `CONCAT`, but it produces the required results so it can't be all bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to build the `$.Rules` JSON array using `FOR JSON`:

```
SELECT 
   t.Id, 
   JSON_MODIFY(t.TemplateValue, '$.Rules', JSON_QUERY(a.Rules)) AS TemplateValue
FROM Template t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT j.RuleName, j.expression
   FROM Rules r
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.RuleJson) WITH (
      RuleName nvarchar(max),
      expression nvarchar(max)
   ) j
   FOR JSON PATH
) a (Rules)
```